# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in nodejs while sending index.html

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a nodejs app using express server(port 8080). I am serving index.html if user hit the server. Here is the code

```
app.get("\*",(req, res, next) => {
     let authToken = req.cookies ? req.cookies.token : null;
     let authorizedUser = authToken ? jwt.verify(authToken,authConfig.secretKey) : null;
     if (authorizedUser) {
          console.log("Authorized User :", authorizedUser);
          res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
     } else {
          res.redirect("http://localhost:9000/login.html")
     }
})
```

I using jwt token base authentication system.If there is token in cookie then I am serving index.html otherwise I am redirecting to my auth-server (on port 9000). There is token present in cookie and it is printing authorized user on server side console

```
[1] Authorized User : { id: 1, iat: 1510813250, exp: 1510814450 }
[1] Checking JWT token : qpp-secret-key
[1] Authorized User : { id: 1, iat: 1510813250, exp: 1510814450 }
[1] Checking JWT token : qpp-secret-key
[1] Authorized User : { id: 1, iat: 1510813250, exp: 1510814450 }
[1] Checking JWT token : qpp-secret-key
[1] Authorized User : { id: 1, iat: 1510813250, exp: 1510814450 }
[1] Checking JWT token : qpp-secret-key
[1] Authorized User : { id: 1, iat: 1510813250, exp: 1510814450 }
[1] Checking JWT token : qpp-secret-key
[1] Authorized User : { id: 1, iat: 1510813250, exp: 1510814450 }
```

I guess this got stuck in loop. Is it due to I am sending index.html file and this again checks the auth system again? How can I solve this?

Comment: What's the request you respond with `index.html` to and how do you create the request in browser? If the `SyntaxError` happens on the browser side, then the browser doesn't expect HTML as a response and fails when trying to parse it.

Comment: i am just hitting the localhost:8080 as the app is running on port 8080

Comment: Is the error happening on the browser?